# Can't print length of tuple.. Why

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

I am very new to python and have trouble printing the length of a variable I have created.

I have tried len(), and I have tried converting to lists, arrays and tuples and so on and cannot get it to print the length correctly.

```
print(k1_idx_label0)

len(k1_idx_label0)
```

And the output is ---

```
(array([  0,   3,   7,  13,  20,  21,  23,  27,  29,  30,  32,  33,  36,
        38,  40,  41,  42,  44,  45,  46,  48,  49,  54,  56,  57,  58,
        62,  65,  68,  69,  70,  72,  76,  80,  82,  83,  84,  85,  88,
        89,  92,  97, 103, 105, 109, 110, 111, 113, 115, 116, 117, 121,
       122, 124, 126, 136, 137, 139, 140, 142, 143, 146, 148, 149, 150,
       151, 153, 155, 156, 157, 158, 160, 161, 165, 166, 168, 173, 174,
       175, 176, 177, 178, 180, 181, 182, 185, 186, 188, 191, 192, 193,
       196, 199, 200, 203, 206, 207, 210, 211, 215, 218, 220, 225, 226,
       227, 228, 232, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 241, 244, 249, 251, 252,
       257, 258, 262, 264, 267, 272, 278, 282, 283, 285, 286, 289, 291,
       297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 305, 307, 308, 309, 313, 315, 317, 318,
       319, 326, 327, 329, 330, 331, 333, 335, 336, 340, 342, 347, 350,
       351, 352, 354, 355, 356, 360, 361, 365, 375, 377, 378, 382, 383,
       385, 386, 387, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 397, 398, 403, 405, 406,
       407, 408, 409, 413, 414, 421, 426, 429, 430, 431, 435, 439, 443,
       444, 445, 446, 447, 449, 452, 454, 455, 456, 457, 460, 462, 463,
       464, 466, 468, 469, 471, 472, 473, 477, 478, 480, 482, 492, 493,
       496, 501, 504, 506, 512, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 523, 528,
       529, 531, 533, 535, 536, 542, 543, 545, 547, 551, 555, 556, 558,
       564, 565, 567, 568, 569], dtype=int64),)
1
```

It keeps printing the length as 1 when there is clearly a lot more than that...

any idea?

Comment: you have tuple with one element - one array - so length of tuple is 1, not length of array

Comment: `(x,)` is Python's way of displaying a one element `tuple`.

Comment: When dealing with Numpy arrays, [`my_array.shape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) is handy attribute to know about, as it'll show the "length" of all the axes. Coming full circle, note the `.shape` is always a tuple, even if 1-long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `k1_idx_label0` variable is actually a tuple containing a single item. That item happens to be a `numpy.array`, but `len()` is correctly reporting the length of the object you’re passing to it.

Instead try:

```
len(k1_idx_label0[0])
```

Which should give you what you want: the length of the first element of the 1-element tuple.

Answer (score 2):

The tuple has just `1` element, if you want to know the size of that element inside the tuple:

```
len(k1_idx_label0[0])
```

if you want to know the size of **all** elements in the tuple:

```
[len(e) for e in k1_idx_label0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
print(len(k1_idx_label0[0]))
```